Generate an equivalent LL(1) language
I need to convert a context free grammar G to an equivalent grammar of type LL(1), but I cannot meet the conditions such that this grammar is in LL(1). I have already performed left factorization and left recursion deletion, but that is not enough. How can I solve this problem?
G: S -> a Y | ( S ) Y | u Y | v Y | z S Y
Y -> Z S | epsilon 
Z -> b S | c S 
I calculated FIRST and FOLLOW for each non-terminal symbol and constructed the parsing table but it turns out that in cells [Y,b] and [Y,c] there are two productions, specifically Y -> Z Y, Y -> epsilon

This is more a cs.stackexchange question.

What is the start symbol? Is it X? It's customary to use the letter S for the start symbol.

Yes X is the starting symbol, I update the rule…so should I ask the question on stackexchange?

What makes you think it's not LL(1)? It avoids recursion and appears to be left-factored. I don't see an ambiguity whereby based on one lookahead symbol, we don't know which production to use. Though Y derives epsilon, it's never followed by anything; all of Y's appearances are in the rightmost position of a production. Almost all the rules begin with a unique nonterminal.  The Z rule could be pulled into Y:  Y -> b S | c S | epsilon.

Your grammar doesn't have Y -> Z Y but in your last paragraph you claim that it does. I think, even if so, it doesn't matter, because this is right recursive. Such a rule adds nothing to FOLLOW(Y), and the fact that Y can derive epsilon just means FOLLOW(Z) includes EOF.

Regarding "in cells [Y,b] and [Y,c] there are two productions, specifically Y -> Z Y, Y -> epsilon". I'm a bit rusty in this university stuff, but why would you have an epsilon production in a table cell where there is a next -symbol b or c, and the symbol Y doesn't have b or c in its FOLLOW set (only FIRST)? That epsilon production is inapplicable.

Given:
S -> a Y
   | ( S ) Y
   | u Y 
   | v Y
   | z S Y

Y -> Z S
   | epsilon

Z -> b S 
   | c S

there is no reason to think that it's not LL(1).
The concern about Y deriving epsilon is placated by the observation that Y only ever appears as the rightmost symbol in productions. Therefore, we know that FOLLOW(Y) is { EOF }.
We can calculate all the sets:
FIRST(a Y) = { a }
FIRST(( s ) Y) = { ( }
FIRST(u Y) = { u }
FIRST(v Y) = { v }
FIRST(z S Y) = { z }

FIRST(Z S) = { b, c }
FIRST(epsilon) = { epsilon }

FIRST(b S) = { b }
FIRST(c S) = { c }

FOLLOW(S) = { ), b, c, EOF }
FOLLOW(Y) = { EOF }
FOLLOW(Z) = { a, (, u, v, z }

So then the predictive parser table looks clean:
     (           a       b       c      u       v       z         EOF
  +-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
S |  ( S ) Y  |  a Y  |       |       |  u Y  |  v Y  |  z S Y  |         |
  +-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
Y |           |       |  Z S  |  Z S  |       |       |         | epsilon |
  +-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
Z |           |       |  b S  |  c S  |       |       |         |         |
  +-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+

The parser only ever follows Y's epsilon rule when facing EOF.

Let me know if I made a mistake somewhere.
